# getting task cancel error while trying to call web api endpoint (hosted in machine A) from machine B in one of the machine for entire domian

Tags: windows, networking, latency

0

I have a web api app hosted over machine A which is called from various machine within a domain.

```
var data = await model.GetDataAsync();
// Throttle the number of requests returned
return Ok(data.Take(maxRequests));
```

Total number of result data = 300 which is huge result payload sending over https over the network.

Within entire domain all of the machine which calling above endpoint works well and entire result packet received well.

But there is one machine B while calling this endpoint fails to get result packet and entire task is cancelled after sometime.

Note - if we're trying to take only few request maxRequests (1-10) out if all data, then machine B able to complete the request and get the result packet.

Question is, what could be missing in machine B? Network Latency, etc. Any registry change ? any configuration change in machine ? Please suggest.

Comment: we can't fix the question with our glass balls but we know that you dont read the guide [ask] ;)